# How to select rows with specific values?

Tags: python, loops, filter

I have a file which has a table with large number of rows and columns.

```
column 2 contain RF, SVM,NV
column 3 contain SMOT,SVM,NV
COLUMN4 contain chi2,fs_based_rd,withour
```

Has these values which repeats on time.
so there will be many rows which will contain `RF`,`smote`,`chi2`
i want all the rows with similar values to save at a place to calculate mean for all similar values.

My file is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ODfD.png)

I want a resulting file like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpjqO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the columns in your file are space-separated, you could use Python's [CSV reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

For example:

```python
import csv

result = []

with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_content = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' ')

    for csv_row in csv_content:
        if csv_row[1:4] == ['RF', 'smote', 'chi2']:
            result.append(csv_row)
```

Comment: thanks for reply but this will append only it will not loop through all possibilit like